# In ASP.NET, File.Create does not work in timer event handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, file

This is my timer code:

```
private static System.Timers.Timer CSVTimer; 

public static void CSVTimer_Start() 
{
    CSVTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    CSVTimer.Interval = 10000;  
    CSVTimer.Elapsed += TCSVCreatEvent; 
    CSVTimer.AutoReset = true;
    CSVTimer.Enabled = true;    
}

public static string s = "";

private static void TCSVCreatEvent(Object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    s += "[ADD0]";
    DatabaseController DC = new DatabaseController();
    string systempath = @"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\DiceGameServerPath\File\SuibaoFile";
    string FileName = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy_MM_dd_HHmmss") + ".csv";
    string text = "test0,test1,test2" + Environment.NewLine;
    //text += DC.ReturnYesterdayData();
    s += "[ADD1]";

    if (!File.Exists(systempath + FileName))
    {
        s += "[ADD2]";
        var NewFile = File.Create(systempath + FileName);
        s += "[ADD3]";
        NewFile.Close();
        s += "[ADD4]";
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(systempath + FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write);
        s += "[ADD5]";
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"));
        s += "[ADD6]";
        sw.Write(text);
        s += "[ADD7]";
        sw.Close();
        s += "[ADD8]";
    }
}
```

I try to use this code to write a `.csv` file, but it does not work.

I print out the `s` to look where to stop, I stop code at "[ADD2]"

Then I copy `TCSVCreatEvent()` code, and use button to call this method, it works very well

So I don't understand why the same code can't work in timer?

*-------------edit-----------*

the code stop in

```
        var NewFile = File.Create(systempath + FileName);
```

Comment: you are just creating file not writing ? var NewFile = File.Create(systempath + FileName);
        s += "[ADD3]";
        NewFile.Close();

Comment: You can use `File.WriteAllLines` or `File.WriteAllText` to write text to a file, without using `FileStream` and `StreamWriter`. See [How to: Write to a Text File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-write-to-a-text-file)

Comment: In order to determine where the program stopped, I deleted those

Comment: you did not started the `timer`. Try calling  `CSVTimer.Start();`

Comment: I have started, in Global.asax Application_Start()

Comment: Put your `TCSVCreatEvent` method inside `try-catch` block and then print error message from caught exception. It should give you a hint on what is wrong.

Comment: @Ňuf I try the IOException , but not get catch message

Comment: Why only `IOException`? It's possible that exception is not caused by an IO operation. Try to catch `System.Exception`, it should catch (nearly) everything.

Comment: ok , i get the error message "System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\DiceGameServerPath\File\SuibaoFile\2018_09_27_095428.csv' is denied. "